# How to plot in excel based on complex cell result

Tags: excel

In an excel spreadsheet I built a model where if I input a value in A1, I get a result in A2 and A3 that are of high interest to me.
To get the A2 and A3 results, I can't just have a formula in A2 and A3 that does the work. Because I don't use macro (I'm on Mac), I need to do some intermediary computation in other cells in order to get the end result.

So the question is : Can I somehow plot the result of A2 and A3 by A1 (X-axis)?

Or said in a different fashion, if I have a range of different value for A1 (say 1000 values). How can I compute the corresponding result A2 and A3 without having to duplicate 1000x the work I've done once?

The intermediary computation is complex to duplicate because it involves working on array and ranges which have values depending on A1. So if I wanted to get 1000 corresponding values the old fashion way, I would have to duplicate and have thousands of different arrays.... Does that make sense?

Edit: 
In this example I want to plot B23 and B24 against different value of B21. Value of B21 would vary between 0 to 10 000 000 by interval of 1000.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwXw25bqBHKxX3ByZG9yR2RpMEU

So to plot this, I guess the first thing to do would be to get column with all the value of B21 that I want. This is easy.
The thing I'm struggling with is how to get the 10 000 corresponding value of B23 and B24.

Comment: "Does that make sense?" - not to me. Could you try to provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I added I example in my edit. I hope it makes more sense

Comment: I think I got it. Maybe for some things Excel is just not the right tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Data Table (Data Tab of Ribbon/What If Analysis/Data Table...).

This feature (and it needs some practice to use it successfully) allows you to generate multiple results.

Data Tables come in two variants: one-variable and two-variable. The former allows you to see the effect of changing the value in a single input cell on an output cell - multiple versions of the input cell are defined and the Data Table provides the corresponding output cell values. The latter shows the effect on an output cell of changes to a pair of input cells.

You want to see the effect of changing `B21` on `B23` and `B24` so you will need to use a one-variable Data Table twice: once to show the effect of changing `B21` on `B23` and once to show the effect of changing `B21` on `B24`. Ensure that you use the same range of changing values for `B21` in both Data Tables. Use the columns from the two Data Tables for plotting your chart.

There are plenty of tutorials, etc on Data Tables, just put `Excel Data Table` into a search engine.